# I can't get post based on its postmeta value and key

Tags: wp-query, post-meta

I tried using the `WP_query` and `get_posts` without success. I need to have a post based on the key/value pair of its `postmeta`. This is my latest try:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => "team_leader_subscription_id",
            'value'     => 38
        )
    ),
    'post_type'         => 'novathon-team',
    'posts_per_page'    => '1'
);

// run query ##
$posts = get_posts( $args );
$q=WP_query($args);

print "DEV: posts:<pre>"; print_r($posts);print_r($q); print "</pre>";
```

It's returning empty array although I know there exists a post which has postmeta `team_leader_subscriptions_id` as key and `38` as value. Why is this hapening? I also tried using `WP_query` with this same arguments in different forms and still nothing. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer. My posts were all in status "private", and by default only the posts with "publish" status are taken.